# useEffect makes axios call twice(?) on pagination change

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios, react-hooks

We have a page which cycles through a users payload (in Redux) using < and > buttons. It literally just replaces the URL Param userId with the next user id in this users payload so fairly simple.

The problem is, when you click < or > it makes the Axios call (inside the useEffect hook) with the new used id (correct) BUT also a call to the previous one as well which is unnecessary and is duplicating calls on every page.

In a nutshell;

1. Click >
2. URL param userId updated with new user id from Redux payload (using generatePath).
3. useEffect makes axios call with the new userId (e.g. 1234) but also the previous one as well.

Am I missing something with hooks here? I've removed everything and just rendered a blank div (no children) but it still makes a call with the old user id. It's driving me mad.

Thanks all.

Comment: What are the dependencies of your useEffect ? Share some code please, we won't be able to help you with just text

Comment: Thanks for your response. There are no dependencies in the useEffect as it does a history.replace with the new URL (which includes the new userId) which fires the useEffect every time with [ ] as the dependencies. I tried with usedId as a dependency but it still made an additional call using the old userId which I don't understand.

Comment: There is something that triggers your useEffect before the page url changes I guess, we need your code to find what's doing that.

Comment: I managed to sort this out. I render a component twice (which makes calls) but differently depending on whether it's mobile or desktop. It seems it was calling both but I'm not sure as they were prefixed with matches && (> sm breakpoint).